# Prove $x+ y+ z= 3,\,x^{\,2}+ y^{\,2}+ z^{\,2}= 9\,\therefore\,y- x\leqq 2\sqrt{3}$ .

Tags: inequality, quadratic-forms, constants, discriminant, sum-of-squares-method

Prove
$$x+ y+ z= 3,\,x^{\,2}+ y^{\,2}+ z^{\,2}= 9\,\therefore\,y- x\leqq 2\sqrt{3}$$
*I have a solution, and I'm looking forward to seeing a nicer one(s), thanks for your interests a lot !*
We have
$$(\,x+ y+ z\,)^{\,2}+ (\,-\,x+ y+ z\,)^{\,2}+ (\,x- y+ z\,)^{\,2}+ (\,x+ y- z\,)^{\,2}= 4(\,x^{\,2}+ y^{\,2}+ z^{\,2}\,)= 36$$
Or
$$\left ( z+ (\,y- x\,) \right )^{\,2}+ \left ( z- (\,y- x\,) \right )^{\,2}+ (\,3- 2\,z\,)^{\,2}= 27$$
Or
$$3\,z^{\,2}- 6\,z+ (\,y- x\,)^{\,2}= 9$$
Or
$$(\,y- x\,)^{\,2}= -\,3(\,z- 1\,)^{\,2}+ 12\leqq 12\,\therefore\,y- x\leqq |\,y- x\,|\leqq 2\sqrt{3}$$
*Q.E.D*. The equality condition occurs when $z= 1\,\therefore\,x+ y= 2\,\therefore\,x= 1- \sqrt{3},\,y= 1+ \sqrt{3}$.

**Say it (Added)**

The @user10354138's solution is so amazing, I try writing the inequality into the homonogeous form, then find $t\!=\!constant$ such that $3(\!y- z\!)^{\!2}\leqq 2t(\!x+ y+ z\!)^{\!2}+ 2(\!1- t\!)(\!x^{\!2}+ y^{\!2}+ z^{\!2}\!)$. That will lead to:
$${\rm discriminant}= 0\,\therefore\,t= -\,2,\,-\,\frac{1}{2},\,1$$
The coefficients of $y^{2}$ and $z^{2}$ both are negative there, I can't make the form like the solution as follow !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\frac1{\sqrt3}(1,1,1), \frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,1,0), \frac1{\sqrt6}(1,1,-2)$ forms an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with respect to the usual inner product, we have
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac13(x+y+z)^2+\frac12(y-x)^2+\frac16(x+y-2z)^2
$$
So
$$
\frac12(y-x)^2\leq (x^2+y^2+z^2)-\frac13(x+y+z)^2=9-3=6
$$
and hence $y-x\leq 2\sqrt3$.

Comment: Your solution is nice with the best form! I added something! Thanks!

Comment: This is a nice solution. I have some suggestions to make it clearer: The OP wrote $y-x\leq 2\sqrt{3}$, I know this is the same as proving that   $y-z\leq 2\sqrt{3}$ because of the symmetry, but just to be consistent would be good that you consider the basis $(1,1,1), (-1,1,0),(-1,-1,2)$. Also, it would be nice that you explain how you constructed this basis, something like if $v=(x,y,z)$ then we are given $|v|^2=9$, $\langle v,(1,1,1)\rangle=3$, and we want to bound $\langle v, (-1,1,0)\rangle$. So, to use the info you essentially combined these data in one formula (Pythagorean theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Let $y-x=d$

$z=3-x-y=3-x-(x+d)=3-2x-d$

$9=x^2+(x+d)^2+(3-d-2x)^2$

Rearrange to form a quadratic equation in $x$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Comment: ${\rm discriminant}= -12(\,d^{\,2}- 12\,)\geqq 0$, very simple and nice! Thank you a real lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another using calculus:

$(x+y+z)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2 +2(xy+yz+zx) \implies (xy+yz+zx)=0 \implies xy = -z(x+y)\implies xy=-z(3-z)$

$(y-x)^2 = (x+y)^2 -4xy$

Now 
$(y-x)^2 = (3-z)^2 +4z(3-z) = 9+6z-3z^2$

Maximum of $(y-x)$ can be found by setting $\frac{d\sqrt{9+6z-3z^2}}{dz} = 0$
so $z = 1$

and Evaluating at $z=1$ $(y-x) \le2\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 0):

*Such an image (this is not an answer) due to **a p u***
[image]